# Finding Cumulative Sum for a non historgram bucket

Tags: elasticsearch, histogram, elasticsearch-aggregation

Is there any way we can calculate cumalative sum for a bucket which is not historgram. As per the doc we can use the cumulative_sum pipeline aggregation only in histogram.

For eg I have two term aggregation company, my_secret_key and a metric valueCount of field "my_secret_key". I want to find the cumulative sum of the value count field.

Is it possible with Elastic search ?

```
{
"aggregations": {
        "company": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "company.keyword"

          },
          "aggregations": {

            "my_secrey_key": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "my_secrey_key"
              },
              "aggregations": {

                "count": {
                  "value_count": {
                    "field": "my_secrey_key"
                  }
                },
                "cumulativeReviewCount" :{
                  "cumulative_sum" :{
                    "buckets_path": "count"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
}
```

PS. this is what I was trying but failed because cumulative_sum only works with historgram. my_secrey_key is a string value.

Comment: Do you need the sum of only the count of the 10 secret_key terms that are being returned? or all the secret_key terms?

Comment: What I was hopping to generate data like : <secret_1, secret_value_count:1, cum_sum: 1>,<secret_2, secret_value_count:2, cum_sum: 3>, <secret_3, secret_value_count:3, cum_sum: 6>.

Cumulative sum of the value counts of the secret key where secrey key is sorted in some order. Yeah I need only the first 10 (or N) secret_keys and corresponding data.